# What am I solving when I use Klein-Gordon equation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, field-theory, schroedinger-equation, klein-gordon-equation

$\newcommand{\Ket}[1]{\left|#1\right>}$
I began to study QFT using David Tong's notes and I have a doubt. This is what the notes says (http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft.html page 21/22).

I work in the Schrödinger picture so my operators $\phi(\boldsymbol{x})$ and $\pi(\boldsymbol{x})$ do not have a time dependence. All time dependence in the Schrödinger picture is encapsulated in the states $\Ket{\psi}$ which evolve according to the Schrödinger equation
\begin{equation}
i\hbar \frac{d}{dt} \Ket{\psi} = H \Ket{\psi}. 
\end{equation}

The notation $\Ket{\psi} $ is deceiving since the wave function in quantum field theory is a
functional of every possible configuration of the field $\phi$.

The simplest relativistic field theory is the Klein-Gordon equation for a real scalar field $\phi(\boldsymbol{x}, t)$

\begin{equation}
\partial_\mu\partial^\mu\phi + m^2\phi = 0. 
\end{equation}

Here is my question: since the Klein-Gordon equation can be "derived" from the Schrödinger equation, why we solve it for the field $\phi(\boldsymbol{x},t)$ and not for the functional $\Ket{\psi}$?

For "derived" here I mean making the guess that the Hamiltonian is
\begin{equation}
H = \sqrt{\boldsymbol{p^2} + m^2}
\end{equation}
and inserting this in the Schrödinger equation.
According to the notes the unknown in the Schrödinger equation is $\Ket{\psi}$ so I would expect to solve for the same thing in the Klein-Gordon equation.

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/779276/2451

Comment: Klein-Gordon as an attempted replacement for the Schroedinger equation is completely different from Klein-Gordon in field theory.

Comment: @ConnorBehan ok so I should see the KG equation only derived from a Lagrangian and take it as the equation of motion of a field, right? It is not related to the SH equation.

Comment: Hi @Alex. I have written an answer for you before you get your question closed. Are you interested in reading it???

Comment: Of course @schris38, a second opinion never hurts, although I must say that I solved my doubts a bit.

Comment: My answer was based more on the functional side of things and Schroedinger functional equation. If you are interest, please leave me a way to contact you. I will just copy and paste the latex code wherever you want me to send it.

Comment: @schris38, you can post it here: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1C2EQDEtRRRVEXNk5EGyT4LB3FeSo_qFomjd2BXkdn1w/edit. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I think I did it. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Klein-Gordon in quantum field theory is *not* a generalization of the Schrödinger equation from ordinary quantum mechanics (whose unknown is the wave-function). It is the equation of motion of the classical theory being quantized, and an equation satisfied by the quantum fields in the Heisenberg picture. The Schrödinger equation remains the Schrödinger equation (with a suitable Hamiltonian and wave-functional).

> Since the Klein-Gordon equation can be "derived" from the Schrödinger equation, why we solve it for the field $\phi(\boldsymbol{x},t)$ and not for the functional $|\psi\rangle$?

In a way, this is just what we do when we move from the Schrödinger picture to the Heisenberg picture :

The Schrödinger picture fields $\hat\phi(\mathbf x),\hat \pi(\mathbf x)$ do not satisfy the KG equation (they are time-independent, by definition). In this picture, the state (ie the wave-functional) evolves in time according to the Schrödinger equation, with the following Hamiltonian :
$$\hat H =\frac 12 \int \text d\mathbf x\left((\hat\pi(x\mathbf )^2 + (\mathbf\nabla \hat\phi(\mathbf x))^2  +m^2 \hat\phi(\mathbf x)^2\right)$$

Moving to the Heisenberg picture, we can reformulate this by having the state/wave-functional be time-independent and the fields evolving according to :
\begin{align}
i\hbar\partial_t{\hat\phi}(\mathbf x,t) &= -[\hat{H},\hat\phi(\mathbf x,t)] \\
i\hbar \partial_t{ \hat\pi}(\mathbf x,t) &= -[\hat{H},\hat{\pi}(\mathbf x,t)]
\end{align}
This, together with the canonical commutation relations, implies that the Heisenberg field $\phi(\mathbf x,t)$ satisfy the Klein-Gordon equation.

On the other hand, there was historically an attempt at using the Klein-Gordon as a generalization of the Schrödinger equation, i.e. having it apply to the wave-function. This is done using the Hamiltonian $H = \sqrt{\mathbf p^2 + m^2}$, but quickly runs into problems, which QFT was designed to avoid.